# How do I make a container accessible over the local network in docker-compose v3?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I would assume I need to set the container to use a bridge network. This seems possible with docker-compose v2, but I can't seem to find resources for docker-compose v3.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ does not even contain "bridge".

Answer (score 0):

By default, docker compose v3 also uses bridge network. If you dont specify network, bridge driver gets used.

If you want to use custom driver, default driver can be changed like this:

```
networks:
  default:
    # Use a custom driver
    driver: custom-driver-1
```

If pre-existing network needs to be used, following option can be used:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```

Comment: Would using a bridge network mean being accessible over the local network? As that didn't appear to be possible.

Comment: By local network, do you mean from localhost? You would still need to expose ports to access container from localhost.

Comment: If you are using bridge network, the container will not be accessible from local network without exposing the container ports to the host(-p or -P option). If you want Containers to be in local network natively, you can use macvlan driver. This is the same with Docker compose v2 or v3.

Comment: `ERROR: plugin "custom-driver-1" not found`